# Cannot re auth user to change email or reset password (Firebase.. Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, credentials

I cannot comment on answers so I have to ask this question, I apologize.

I am getting an **error** on Xcode when trying to re authenticate the user so their email and or password is changed.

Here is the code I've written.

```
    var credential: AuthCredential

    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
            // re authenticate the user
        user?.reauthenticate(with: credential) { error in
            if let error = error {
                // An error happened.
            } else {
                // User re-authenticated.
            }
        }


        }
```

I get an error that states **Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type 'AuthDataResultCallback?' (aka 'Optional<(Optional, Optional) -> ()>')**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the reauthenticate function returns a tuple, so you have to change the code:

```
var credential: AuthCredential

let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

// re authenticate the user
user?.reauthenticate(with: credential) { (authDataResult, error) in
    if let error = error {
        // An error happened.
    } else {
        // Use `user` property of result to check is successful.
    }
}
```

[AuthDataResultCallback](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Type-Definitions#/c:FIRAuth.h@T@FIRAuthDataResultCallback)

[FIRAuthDataResult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRAuthDataResult)